# Definition of meromorphic function on complex manifolds

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, meromorphic-functions

There are typically four(or more?) definition of meromorphic function on Riemann surface and three definitions of meromorphic function on complex manifolds, I want to show they are equivalent (I will not consider the additional one on Riemann surface as it's specified for that case):

**Definition 1** Define the sheaf of meromorphic function to be
$$\mathcal{M}_X=\coprod_{x \in X} \mathcal{M}_{X, x}$$
with topology that open sets are union of $\{G_x/H_x\mid x\in V\}\subset \mathcal{M}_X$ with $V$ open and $G,H \in \mathcal{O}_X(V)$. Meromorphic function is the section of the sheaf above.

**Definition 2** the sheaf of meromorphic function is sheafification of the following sheaf:

Let $U$ be an open subset $U = \cup U_i$ for $U_i$ connected component then we have the presheaf $$U\mapsto \Pi_i \text{ Frac}(\mathcal{O}_X(U_i))$$

**it's not hard to show the sheaf in definition 1is the Etale space assciated to this presheaf.**

**Definition 3** Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be open. A meromorphic function $f$ on $U$ is a function on the complement of a nowhere dense subset $S \subset U$ with the following property: There exist an open cover $U=\bigcup U_i$ and holomorphic functions $g_i, h_i: U_i \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\left.\left.h_i\right|_{U_i \backslash S} \cdot f\right|_{U_i \backslash S}=\left.g_i\right|_{U_i \backslash S}$.

---

I was trying to show that definition 3 are equivalent to 1 (and 2), however I don't have good idea.

---

I see the point is the section of the sheaf, is a continuous map from $X\to \mathcal{M}_X$, with the topology, contains all the $$[(U,G/H)]=\{G_x/H_x \mid x \in U\}$$ being open in the etale space topology.

Therefore if $s:X\to \mathcal{M}_X$ such that $s_x = G_x / H_x$ then locally for where $G$ and $H$ are defined, $s_y = G_y/H_y$ for $y\in U$(that's guaranteed by the continuity of the section). Therefore, locally the information of the section is equivalent to the information of pair $(G,H)$, definition 3 use that locally information $(G_\alpha,H_\alpha)$ to define the section.

And you see that $U_i$ in definition 3 are the sets of open subsets that the representative element $(G,H)$ are defined.

Comment: It may be a bit pedantic, but there is no "the" complex manifold, only complex manifolds!

Comment: Ok Dider ,corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two definitions that are pretty much the ones you mention. Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a complex manifold where $\mathcal{O}_X$ is the sheaf of $\mathbb{C}$-valued holomorphic functions on $X$.

1.$\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf on $X$ s.t. it is sheaf associated to the presheaf
$$U\mapsto \mathcal{S}^{-1}(U)\mathcal{O}_X(U)$$
where $\mathcal{S}(U)=\{a\in\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)\ |\ \forall x\in U,a_{x}\text{ is not a zero-divisor of }\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is a subsheaf of sets of $\mathcal{O}_X$, see [this stacks project page](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01X1).

2.$\mathcal G$ is a sheaf on $X$ s.t.
$$U\mapsto\{\text{meromorphic functions on }U\}$$
where a meromorphic function on $U$ (see A course in complex analysis by Fischer, Wolfgang and Lieb, Ingo) is a holomorphic function $f:U\to \mathbb{P}^1$ of complex manifolds s.t. there exists an open covering $\{U_i,i\in I\}$ of $U$, $g_i,h_i\in \mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ s.t.

(1) for all $i$, $h_i$ is nowhere $\equiv 0$, i.e. $h_i|_V\not\equiv 0$ for all non-empty open subset $V\subset U_i$.

(2) $g_ih_j=g_jh_i$ over $U_i\cap U_j$

(3)for all $i$, $f|_{U_i}=\frac{g_i}{h_i}:U_i \to \mathbb{P}^1$.

A non-rigorous proof is as following:

1. Let $U$ be non-empty open in $X$. We know $$\mathcal{G}(U)=\{\text{meromorphic functions }f:U\to\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}\}.$$
2. We know \begin{align}
   \mathcal{F}(U)= & \{(\frac{g_{x}}{h_{x}},U_{x})_{x\in U}\in\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}:\text{for all }x\in U\text{, there} \\
    & \text{exists an open neighborhood }V\subset U\text{ of }x\text{, and} \\ 
    & \frac{g_{V}}{h_{V}}\in\mathcal{F}(V)\text{ s.t. for all }y\in V, \\
    & (\frac{g_{y}}{h_{y}},U_{y})=(\frac{g_{V}}{h_{V}},V)\in\mathcal{F}_{y}\}.
   \end{align}
3. Let $f\in\mathcal{G}(U)$, then there exists an open covering $(U_{i})_{i\in I}$ of $U$ and $g_{i},h_{i}\in\mathcal{O}_{X}(U_{i})$ s.t. $h_{i}$ nowhere $\equiv0$, $g_{i}h_{j}=g_{j}h_{i}$ on $U_{ij}=U_{i}\cap U_{j}$ and $f|_{U_{i}}\equiv\frac{g_{i}}{h_{i}}$.
4. For each $x\in U$, there exists $i_{x}\in I$ s.t. $x\in U_{i_x}$.
5. For each $i\in I$, $h_{i}$ is nowhere $\equiv0$ so $h_{i}$ is not $\equiv0$ over any non-empty open subset of $U_{i}$. So for all $x\in U_i$, $(h_{i},U_{i})\neq0$ in the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{x}$, hence it is not a zero-divisor and thus $h_{i}\in \mathcal{S}(U_i)$ (the only zero-divisor is zero since the stalk is an integral domain, check the identity theorem on multivariable complex analysis, see Introduction to complex analysis in several variables by Scheidemann, Volker).
6. So we have an element $(\frac{g_{i_{x}}}{h_{i_{x}}},U_{i_{x}})_{x\in U}\in\prod_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}_{x}$.
7. Let $x\in U$, then for all $y\in U_{i_{x}}$, we have $(\frac{g_{i_{y}}}{h_{i_{y}}},U_{i_{y}})=(\frac{g_{i_{x}}}{h_{i_{x}}},U_{i_{x}})$ in $\mathcal{F}_{y}$. Thus $(\frac{g_{i_{x}}}{h_{i_{x}}},U_{i_{x}})_{x\in U}\in\mathcal{F}(U)$.
8. Reversely given an element $(s_{x})_{x\in U}\in\mathcal{F}(U)$. For each $x\in U$, we can find an open neighborhood $U_{x}\subset U$ of $x$ and $\frac{g_{x}}{h_{x}}\in\mathcal{S}(U_{x})^{-1}\mathcal{O}(U_{x})$ s.t. for all $y\in U_{x}$, $(\frac{g_{x}}{h_{x}},U_{x})=s_{y}$.
9. Then $(U_{x})_{x\in U}$ clearly forms an open covering of $U$.
10. Fix $x\in U$, by definition for all $y\in U_{x}$, $(h_{x},U_{x})\neq0\in\mathcal{O}_{y}$.
11. Assume for a contradiction that $h_{x}$ is not nowhere $\equiv0$, then $h_{x}\equiv0$ over some non-empty open subset of $U_{x}$, so it descends to zero over some stalk in $U_{x}$, contradiction.
12. Fix $x,y\in U$, if $U_{x}\cap U_{y}\neq\emptyset$, then for any $z\in U_{x}\cap U_{y}$, we have $s_{z}=(\frac{g_{x}}{h_{x}},U_{x})=(\frac{g_{y}}{h_{y}},U_{y})\in\mathcal{F}_{z}$.
13. So there exists $W\subset U_{x}\cap U_{y}$ s.t. $g_{x}h_{y}=g_{y}h_{x}$ over $W$. In particular $g_{x}(z)h_{y}(z)=g_{y}(z)h_{x}(z)$. Hence they agree over $U_{x}\cap U_{y}$.
14. Hence the data glues to a holomorphic map $f:U\to\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$ s.t. $f|_{U_{x}}=\frac{g_{x}}{h_{x}}$ for all $x\in U$.
15. It can be shown that the two operations are inverse to each other, well defined (i.e. independent of choices of all those data) and preserve the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structure, and they are compatible with restriction maps. We omit the details.
16. It follows that the two definitions of sheaf of meromorphic functions on $X$ agree.

Comment: Thank you @Z Wu , that's a very exellent answer